# Store private keys with ionic

Tags: javascript, api, ionic-framework, key, microservices

Im using ionic to create a hybrid mobile app, this app will use a micro service architecture as the backend and i want to assure that only my app will be able to reach the microservices.

So i came up with a simple solution: Encripting all the params sended with an HMAC "X" key and sending this parameters with the encription token, so in the backend i'll repeat the process with the same "X" key and if both tokens are the same i can know this key would change.

My problem is related to storing the "X" key in Ionic, because this is mainly javascript so its easily inspectionable, i was wondering if there is any way to store dynamic private keys (i want to change the keys every week or so) inside the ionic app without hardcoding it.

Thanks for your help!